# Android object's convex look

Tags: android, object, convex

I am new to android animations, so if someone can help me, I want to transform an object, lets say a rectangle to have a convex look. Can I do that with some of the functions, like lets say skew or... If someone has an idea or a sample code I would really appreciate it. Thank u in advance

Answer (score 0):

The Android 2D libraries are pretty basic, but I think you could use four [ArcShape](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/shapes/ArcShape.html)s to simulate the look of a convex rectangle.